# replace a line into a big string variable with perg_replace function in php

Tags: php

i have 2 variables  `$bigStr` and `$linesToReplace`. I want, if any line matches in both, (array) `$linesToReplace` and (string) `$bigStr`, then replace it into the `$bigStr` and also highlight.

what i have done so far is here:

```
$bigStr = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $linesToReplace).'/i', '<span style="color:red;"><b>$0</b></span>', $bigStr);
```

but it works for only one word not for a whole line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is something along these lines...

```
$bigStr = 'Hello foo and bar and baz.';
$linesToReplace = array('/foo/','/bar/','/baz/');

$bigStr =  preg_replace($linesToReplace, '<span style="color:red;"><b>$0</b></span>', $bigStr);
```

This will yield something along the lines of:

[image]

Make sure you add your delimiters (/ in this case) to each element in your `$linesToReplace` array

Comment: one problem accrue, case sensitive